# Create a list of empty dictionaries

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I want to create a list of variable length containing empty directories.

```
n = 10 # size of list
foo = []
for _ in range(n)
    foo.append({})
```

Would you do this the same way, or is there something like?

```
a = [{}*n]
```

Answer (score 48, accepted):

List comprehensions to the rescue!

```
foo = [{} for _ in range(n)]
```

There is no shorter notation, I am afraid. In Python 2 you use `xrange(n)` instead of `range(n)` to avoid materializing a useless list.

The alternative, `[{}] * n` creates a list of length `n` with only *one* dictionary, referenced `n` times. This leads to nasty surprises when adding keys to the dictionary.

Comment: The answer previously given would have been fine for me,
because I do not care about references since I convert the whole list to JSON in the next step. But I will accept your answer because it is of more general use.

Comment: @MartinFlucka: It's not a good practice to use `[{}] * 3` even if this is just for JSON; you'll find yourself forgetting about that little detail and when you later on add keys and values anyway you run into a nasty surprise.

Comment: @MartijnPieters You are totally right, better safe than sorry.

Comment: @j08lue: That's why I mention it. But for Python 3, `xrange()` was renamed to `range()` and improved, my initial example assumes Python 3.

Comment: @MartijnPieters: So many years as a Python dev and surprisingly I didn't hit this case until now! I was totally baffled at the things Python was doing after creating [{}]*n and I was about to hop on the existential crisis train! Your answer helped me clear up the queries! Big Thanks!

Comment: Just got rekt by `[{}] * n`. Does this basically mean that preallocating lists in python is not "pythonic"? Lists have ended up being a big pain in general in python but I have a feeling I'm just not using them as intended...

Comment: @Justin: pre-allocating lists is fine if that makes an algorithm easier to work with or perform better. Just use the right technique. Multiplying a list does not create copies of the elements in the source list, that's all.